# Vectorize growth calculation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to create a vectorized solution for the following problem:

```
    bp   sp    pct_growth
0  1.0  2.0         100.0
1  1.0  1.5          50.0
2  1.0  2.0         100.0
```

I need to calculate the absolute cumulative growth based of an initial quantity (assuming 1000):

```
    bp   sp    pct_growth    abs_growth
0  1.0  2.0         100.0        2000.0
1  1.0  1.5          50.0        3000.0
2  1.0  2.0         100.0        6000.0
```

The following code works, but I'd like to find a vectorized solution:

```
a = [{'bp': 1.0, 'sp': 2}, {'bp': 1.0, 'sp': 1.5}, {'bp': 1.0, 'sp': 2}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(a)

df2['pct_growth'] = df2[['bp','sp']].pct_change(axis=1)['sp'] * 100

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
  if index == 0:
    df2.loc[index, 'abs_growth'] = 1000 + 1000*row['pct_growth']/100
  else:
    df2.loc[index, 'abs_growth'] = df2.loc[index-1, 'abs_growth'] + df2.loc[index-1, 'abs_growth']*row['pct_growth']/100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate absolute growth rate by `(1 + df.pct_growth / 100).cumprod()` and then multiply by the `base` defined by your logic:

```
base = 1000
df['abs_growth'] = (1 + df.pct_growth / 100).cumprod() * base

df
    bp   sp  pct_growth  abs_growth
0  1.0  2.0       100.0      2000.0
1  1.0  1.5        50.0      3000.0
2  1.0  2.0       100.0      6000.0
```